# Identify 2000-2010 movie: a group of people are isolated in a complex, and forced to kill one another to survive

Tags: story-identification, movie, actor-identification

Please note that I have not seen this movie in about 20 years, I may have false memories and unintentionally give false details.

## General Info

I seen this movie between year 2002-2008, year up or year down. It was approximately released between those years.

The movie is dubbed to Spanish of Spain, because I seen it in Spanish language.

Probably it is a B movie or TV movie from USA, because I think I remember American actors in the movie, and the movie scenes and how it is directed seems mostly Hollywood style for me.

The protagonist, which was a middle-aged man, I think it could be a famous secondary American actor from that decade.

## Genre

The genre is 'Isolation Horror' but much more focused to action than to horror, so another good terms to define the genre could be 'Battle Royale' or 'Deathmatch'.

The movie has various action scenes and, from what I think I remember, a little of sci-fi too.

## Plot (as I think I remember)

A middle-aged man (the protagonist) and several other people who do not know each other, meet in one place. They are then taken away and locked up against their own will in a kind of closed complex, a facility or build. Each person is put in a different room, separated each other, and forced to kill each other. Whoever survives will be able to leave that place (win the game).

I remember this people who were forced to kill each other, they find (or someone gives to them) weapons like guns, shotguns or machine guns.

I can't remember anything in particular too clearly, but I think all of that above is pretty much what I said.

Now all the next sentences are just speculation:

**UPDATE:** It is possible that the protagonist and the strangers came to a a place and everyone gets inside a bus or other kind of vehicle, and then they go direct to the building. Once they are inside the building, they can't escape until everyone kills each other.

It is possible that the protagonist and the strangers came to that place by invitation, as if to earn a big amount of money (something similar to the movie '[House on Haunted Hill](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0185371/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)').

It is also possible that the protagonist lost the memories of him when he is locked in that place to fight to the death against others. Maybe because a drug to sleep that produced Amnesia on him (something similar to the movie '[ARQ](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5640450/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0)').

And also, I think there is a girl or a boy in the place, a very young person, and the protagonist finds him and decides to protect him at all costs so that others do not kill him. I think at the end of the movie the protagonist sacrifices himself to save this younger person.

Perhaps it is also possible that there was a kind of "telepathic communication" between the protagonist and the evil owner / leader / creator of this deatmatch. I may be wrong and that this is just a false memory, but I think I remember that the protagonist is spoken telepathically or perhaps through an implanted chip, or maybe just a TV or a CAM or through loudspeakers, and they harass him a bit in this way to make him lose his faith and his courage.

## Research and References

I looked into loads and loads of filmographies from leading and secondary actors like [Eric Roberts](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000616/?ref_=fn_al_nm_1), [John Saxon](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0768334/?ref_=tt_ov_st), [Alec Baldwin](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000285/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0), [Stephen Baldwin](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000286/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0) or [Corin Nemec](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0005269/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0), because they are good candidates who resemble the vague memories that I have of the appearance of the actor. But as it is evident, I did not find the movie in their filmographies. Nevertheless, there is always the big chance that I have just missed this movie in any filmography from those actors, because they have many movies and I tried to discard any movie that at first sight seems not dubbed to Spanish of Spain.

To help you discard, these are some movies dubbed to Spanish of Spain with similarities with the movie that I'm looking for are:

- AfterParty (2013)
- Arena (2011)
- Armored (2009)
- ARQ (2016)
- Battle Royale (2000)
- Battle Royale 2 (2003)
- Bloodsucking bastards (2015)
- Botched (2007)
- Breathing Room (2008)
- Cube (1997) (and the entire saga)
- Dead Scared (2004)
- Death Factory (2002)
- Devil (2010)
- Downrange (2018)
- Escape Room (2017)
- Escape Room (2019)
- Exam (2009)
- Falling Down (1993)
- Fantasy Island (2020)
- Fermat's Room (2007)
- Free Fire (2016)
- Gamer (2009)
- Guns Akimbo (2019)
- High-Rise (2015)
- [House of 9](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0395585/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) (2005)
- House on Haunted Hill (1999)
- House on Haunted Hill 2 (2007)
- Identity (2003)
- Kill 'em All (2012)
- La cueva (2014)
- La Horde (2009)
- Mayhem (2017)
- Mean guns (1997) (this in particular has a lot of similarities, it made me doubt!)
- My Little Eye (2002)
- Night of the Demons (1988) (and the entire saga)
- Night of the Demons (Remake) (2009)
- Nine Lives (2002)
- [Operation: Endgame](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1268987/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) (2010)
- Predators (2010)
- Ready or Not (2019)
- Reservoir Dogs (1992)
- SAW (2004) (and the entire saga)
- Series 7: The Contenders (2001)
- [Severance](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0464196/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) (2006)
- Steel Trap (2007)
- Surviving the Game (1994)
- The 33 (2015)
- [The Belko Experiment](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1082807/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0) (2016)
- The Cabin in the Woods (2011)
- [The Condemned](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0443473/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) (2007)
- The Condemned 2 (2015)
- The Descent (2006)
- The Experiment (2001)
- The Experiment (2010)
- The Haunting (1999)
- The Hole (2001)
- [The Human Race](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1427298/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_2) (2013)
- The Hunger Games (2013) (and the entire saga)
- The Hunt (2020)
- The Killing Room (2009)
- The Purge (2013) (and the entire saga)
- The Raid (2011)
- The Raid 2 (2014)
- The running man (1987)
- [The Tournament](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0471041/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) (2009)
- Thir13en Ghosts (2001)
- Time Trap (2017)
- Tower Block (2012)
- Virus (1999)
- Wilderness (2006)
- Unknown (2006)

And some more that you can also discard. This list are of movies that are not dubbed to Spanish of Spain or whose I'm unsure they are dubbed:

- Abducted (2013)
- Acid Factory (2009)
- After Effect (2012)
- Are you scared? (2006)
- Are you scared? 2 (2009)
- Circle (2015)
- Die (2010)
- Game of Assassins (2013)
- Hunger (2009)
- Inhuman Resources (2012)
- Kill Theory (2009)
- Nine Dead (2009)
- Raze (2013)
- Seven Below (2012)
- The Divide (2011)
- The Employer (2013)
- The incite mill (2010)
- The Task (2011)
- Triangle (2009)
- Vile (2011)

I really looked in thousands of these kind of movies, without luck. There are lists of 'Isolation Horror' movies in IMDB and in some other websites. I think the movie I'm looking for would not be a much known movie like are those from the list.

In the worst case I can think, it is possible that the movie in reality could be a TV mini series of two or three chapters, or a long-length episode from a anthological sci-fi series (like [The Outer Limits](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112111/?ref_=fn_al_tt_4)).

Comment: That's a good first question. And the telepathy would suggest a science fiction or fantasy film.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly comment. Anyway, and to be honest, the telepathy it could just be a TV or a CAM or kind of monitor in the ceiling. As I said my memories are very confused at this point, but I would say that there was some sci-fi in the weapons and with this "telepathy" or mechanism to communicate with the "players".

Comment: I have a memory of watching something like this, probably from Netflix, pre-2010.  A few people were locked in a warehouse full of death traps.  The guy who set it all up talked to them over loudspeakers.

Comment: Just a long shot, but the Cube movies (https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/Cube) match some of your memories.

Comment: Alec Baldwin is not a "secondary actor" like the others listed.

Comment: @LAK yes it could be loudspeakers!! Maybe you could remember something more like the name of the movie or the year or an actor?, it could help me a lot. None from the 'Cube' saga is the one I'm looking for.

Comment: @Buzz yes you have reason but at certain point of their career every leading actor becomes a secondary or support actor, or I think so. Just try to excuse me to add the great 'Alec Baldwin' in the same bag, is not my intention to call any actor "secondary", all of those actors that I mentioned are great for me.

Comment: Here are two movies to look into: 'Exam' and 'Breathing Room': https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1258197/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1  https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1220706/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl

Comment: @LAK I knew those two movies, they are not the one I'm looking for. Thanks for your help!. The movie with the speakers could be.

Comment: You're welcome! I haven't been able to find the one I'm remembering, but found those others that could be yours.  One more is 'Aquarium': https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0482159/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_3

Comment: What a forgotten french movie that 'Aquarium', I can't even find a single image of the film more than the cover, I can't even find it in eMule (the warehouse for finding any old movie). I don't have more resources to try find it. As of this I doubt it was even dubbed in other language than french, so I wonder if I could discard it. Thanks again. I really hope you could remember the movie you mentioned in your first comment. That really could be the right movie my friend.

Comment: Not "[the running man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Running_Man_(1987_film))"? That has a fair number of the elements, but it has Schwarzenegger as a main character.

Comment: Very small chance you're thinking of The Island (2005) - the isolation and violence match, the battle royale does not https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0399201/plotsummary

Comment: Thanks for your help but it is not 'the running man" neither 'the island'. I'm pretty sure the movie I'm looking for is not that much known, so we should discard any AAA production like those two.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because media provided as the accepted answer is not a science fiction or fantasy work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the movie, finally!, but when I found it I realized that I had a mental cocoa in my head because some things and scenes that I vaguely remembered I associated with the genre of pure action with firearms and a death game. I have had to mix an infinity of things and details from older movies, such as the year of the movie, and certain similarities with the other movie that I mentioned about 'Mean Guns'... that don't have much to do with this movie that I was looking for the truth ... now I realize my failures, I'm sorry folks.

This is the movie:

Rebirth (2016)

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4902716/

Comment: Just watched through it, and checked a plot summary, and there are no fantasy or science fiction aspects, although it is a creepy movie.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought reading through your description was about the movie [The Thing (2011)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thing_%282011_film%29), where the characters are "isolated" at an Antartic base. Some characters eventually begin to kill each other due to reasons within the film. For more info I suggest looking at the plot in Wikipedia.
Or maybe it might be the other movie [The Thing (1982)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thing_(pel%C3%ADcula_de_1982)). There isn't a Wikipedia page for it in english.

My second thought was about the movie [Escape Room (2019)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_Room_(2019_film)), but it doesn´t fit within the time parameters you established.

Comment: Thanks for the help but the movie I'm looking for it is not any kind of monster's horror movie. Just a group of random people that comes to a complex or building and are isolated killing each other with weapons due the rules of the game to survive and escape from there.